# Different results between old and new ternary conditional operators in Python

Tags: python

Just a small question about ternary conditional operator which has confused me for a long time.

Code for example (python 2.7):

```
>>> x, y = None, 3
>>> x, y
(None, 3)
>>> (x == None and x or y)
3
>>> (x != None and x or y)
3
>>> (x if x == None else y)
```

The third and forth lines are old-style conditional operator. Both give the same result. And obviously,
the former takes "wrong" result. Maybe it's not wrong according to python. But it's very easy to make
the mistake in program and without explicit error.

The fifth line are new-style from version 2.5 according to the book "Core python programming" (Wesley J. Chun) and its return is right.

Does someone know something about this?

Comment: whats the question? ...  the "new" version is more verbose (explicit is better than implicit)

Comment: Only the last one is the ternary operator, which is perhaps why it works?

Comment: @JoranBeasley, and most importantly, *correct*. Unlike the old version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your third and fourth lines aren't a ternary operator.  They're an attempt to hack a ternary operator using other operators, but, as you saw, they don't really work, because the logical operators you're using depend on the notion of "boolean falseness", not just of the condition, but of the results you want to return based on the condition.  The real ternary operator was added precisely so you don't have to use that sort of fakery anymore.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known problem with this "conditional operator" hack. it does not work.

`x == None` => true. Continue to the "and" part, as expected.

`and x` => false (since `x` is `None`, and `None` is false). the whole `and` expression evaluates to false, hence `or y` comes into play. result is `y`.

Comment: Yes, I got it. Thanks for your logical analysis.

Answer (score 1):

It's not wrong. It's just the way that truthy and falsy values work.

`(x != None and x or y)` is evaluated like `((x != None) and x) or y`, which will return `y` in both cases if `x` is falsy. `False and False` and `True and False` are both `False`, so the short-circuiting `or` will return `y`.

The `and ... or` trick isn't actually a ternary operator, as there's no condition. It's just relying on the fact that `or` short-circuits, so if `x != None and x` is truthy, `y` won't be evaluated. The new-style *is* an actual ternary operator.